# Using custom variables in node template

Tags: variables, preprocessor, drupal-7

I create variables in my preprocess page template

```
function hook_theme_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
$vars['myvariable'] = "some text here";
}
```

Now I need to use these in my node template, I can see it when I dsm($node) but when I try

```
print $myvariable;
```

I get nothing.

Comment: If you want to remove your sensitive information permanently, I recommend flagging your post for moderator attention and requesting that the edit history be wiped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mytheme_preprocess_page` will preprocess the *page* template (i.e. `page.tpl.php`), not the *node* template (i.e. `node.tpl.php`). If you want to add vars to the node template you need to process that particular template with `hook_preprocess_node()`:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  $node = $vars['node']; // Just in case you need it

  if ($node->type == 'news_page') {
    $vars['myvariable'] = "some text here";
  }
}
```

Comment: what if it is a custom node called news_page, which has it's own  template node--news_page.tpl.php

Comment: You could check the type of the node in your preprocess function, I've updated the code in the answer